# Installing Gitolite on NAS - FATAL: have errors but logging failed

Tags: nas, gitolite

I'm trying to install Gitolite on my Synology DiskStation, following these [instructions](http://www.bluevariant.com/2012/05/comprehensive-guide-git-gitolite-synology-diskstation/).

Under **Install Gitolite on the DiskStation and Run Setup**, when I run the Gitolite install command:

```
DiskStation> /volume1/homes/git/gitolite/install -ln /bin
```

I get the following error:

```
FATAL: have errors but logging failed!

2012-05-31.00:10:22 no GL_LOGFILE env var
2012-05-31.00:10:22 die could not symlink /volume1/home/git/gitolite/src/gitolite to /bin<<newline>> at /volume1/home/git/gitolite/install line 71<<newline>>
```

I am very new to all of this. Does anyone know what this means, and how I can fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 issues:

The new GitoliteV3 (g3) doesn't handle gracefully the lack of a 'logs' directory, which should be present by default in `$HOME/.gitolite`.
See [Rc.pm](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/lib/Gitolite/Rc.pm#L38):

```perl
$rc{LOG_TEMPLATE} = "$ENV{HOME}/.gitolite/logs/gitolite-%y-%m.log";
$rc{GL_LOGFILE} = $ENV{GL_LOGFILE} ||= gen_lfn( $rc{LOG_TEMPLATE} );
```

[`Common.pm`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/lib/Gitolite/Common.pm#L242):

```perl
sub gl_log {
    # the log filename and the timestamp come from the environment. If we get
    # called even before they are set, we have no choice but to dump to STDERR
    # (and probably call "logger").

    logger_plus_stderr( "$ts no GL_LOGFILE env var", "$ts $msg" ) if not $ENV{GL_LOGFILE};
    open my $lfh, ">>", $ENV{GL_LOGFILE} or logger_plus_stderr( "open log failed: $!", $msg );
```

<del>Create a logs directory: `mkdir -p $HOME/.gitolite/logs` and relaunch the installation</del>.
As [sitearm](https://superuser.com/users/140534/sitaram) (who, I can only assume from his empty profile, is [Sitaram Chamarty](https://github.com/sitaramc), the creator/maintainer of Gitolite), this shouldn't be needed.
And from the OP's [answer below](https://superuser.com/a/431279/141), this *wasn't* needed anyway.

sitearm adds:

> The `LOGFILE` error message is misleading; it happens when the installation directory is not in `$PATH`.

The [latest commit](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/commit/a171053ab3626c69315c4a4d7966dd7aa2799df5) on `Common.pm` (June, 16th 2012) has indeed replaced the error message in order to *not* reference anymore the mysterious `GL_LOGFILE`:

```
logger_plus_stderr( "errors found before logging could be setup", "$msg" ) if not $ENV{GL_LOGFILE};
```

---

Note that if you have your own perl in a non-standard path, none of those install scripts will work, since their shebang references `/usr/bin/perl` instead of a `/usr/bin/env perl`...

---

Second issue:

```
could not symlink /volume1/home/git/gitolite/src/gitolite to /bin
```

<del>Check if you have the rights to symlink in `/bin`. Are you root?</del>
As mentioned below

```
DiskStation> /volume1/homes/git/gitolite/install -ln
```

(without `/bin`) would keep everything under `$HOME` (no /bin writing access issue)

---

I generally prefer a local installation

```
 $HOME/gitolite/github/install -to $HOME/gitolite/bin
```

(so '`-to`' instead of '`-ln`', with an absolute path in my account rather than a system path) with:

- `github` the name of the local clone of `https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite`
- `$HOME/gitolite/bin` a directory that I have added to my `$PATH`.

Comment: Please do not suggest solutions that involve anything that is not in the documentation. `mkdir -p ...` is one such well-meaning but wrong suggestion. If you think it is required, let me know my documentation is missing something and we can discuss it. The LOGFILE error message is misleading; it happens when the installation directory is not in $PATH. Please run `./install -h` for details on various options on this.

Comment: @sitaram ok, answer edited. the `mkdir` is the least of my issues with g3: all your scripts reference a `#!/usr/bin/perl`, which is incompatible with my non-standard perl installation. A `#!/usr/bin/env perl` would be more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

The following command was a typo:

```
DiskStation> /volume1/homes/git/gitolite/install -ln /bin
```

Earlier in the post it has you setup a $HOME/bin directory for the git user.  Run the same command but leave the specified /bin directory argument off, and gitolite will default to $HOME/bin which exists and is writeable by the git user.

Run this instead:

```
DiskStation> /volume1/homes/git/gitolite/install -ln
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran the command `gitolite/install -ln /usr/bin/`

For me, the symlink error was due to the `git` user not having the requisite permissions to symlink to `/usr/bin`. I simply added the `git` user to `wheel` group in `/etc/group` file and that worked like a charm.