# Cannot login to ssh after installing Gitolite? PTY allocation request failed on channel 0

Tags: git, nas, gitolite

After I installed Gitolite onto my Synology DiskStation NAS as per these instructions:
http://www.bluevariant.com/2012/05/comprehensive-guide-git-gitolite-synology-diskstation/

I realized that I managed to install gitolite, but for whatever reason I was not able to run the installation using the user "git" - but I was able to do so as "root"

After installing, I logged out.
But now every time I tried to login via ssh again:
$ ssh root@iptonas

I got this error:
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0

I read somewhere that gitolite disables ssh logins now?  How else can I get back into shell..?

Comment: Did my previous answer worked? http://superuser.com/a/430902/141

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
error: PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
```

Perfectly normal, expected, and not blocking (ie the ssh operation would pursue)

However, you did the installation as root, which is bad, especially when you consider the [ssh Gitolite page](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/ssh.html):

> **If you're installing gitolite, you're a "system admin", like it or not**.
>   If you're using the default ssh mode (i.e., not http mode), ssh is a necessary skill. Please take the time to learn at least enough to get passwordless access working.

The key aspect to understand in Gitolite is its usage of **[forced command](http://oreilly.com/catalog/sshtdg/chapter/ch08.html#22858)**, in order to deny interactive shell and to intercept any command (including the git commands), allowing it to enforce access control to Git repos.

That means your `~root/.ssh/authorized_keys` file contains line with:

```
command="/devit_home/users/vobadm/gitpoc/ce7/gitolite/bin/gitolite-shell gitoliteadm",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-for        warding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa AAAAB3N
```

The `no-port-forwarding` is responsible for that warning message "`PTY allocation request failed on channel 0`". But that doesn't prevent Gitolite operations to run properly.

See "[how does gitolite use all this ssh magic?](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/glssh.html)".

For ssh issue, look into "[SSH troubleshooting](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/sts.html)".
You need to gain access to your server by another way than `ssh`, and remove the line beginning by `command` in  `~root/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

---

> Do you know how I might use Telnet to redo the gitolite installation process?

Once logged as root:

- remove the line beginning by command in the `~root/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.
- make sure your root public key is registered in that same file (so without any '`command=`' in front of it.

That will ensure a root access through ss.

Then redo the installation, but with a `sudo git` first.
you must be 'git' when doing that installation.

You must first generate on the client side an `git` private ssh key and a `git.pub` public key.
Copy the public key on the server: you will pass that public key to the `gitolite install` command.

And as [Ryan](https://superuser.com/users/137444/ryan) mentions in [his answer](https://superuser.com/a/431279/141), uses

```
DiskStation> /volume1/homes/git/gitolite/install -ln
```

(in order to link the installation to `~git/bin` instead of the "system path root-protected" `/bin` directory).

Comment: Thank you!  That clarifies things a bit. But what do you mean exactly by 'it's bad that I installed via root'? What are the ramifications? And is there a way to take a step back and redo it properly?

Comment: @Jay The inconvenience of a root installation is the possibility to lock oneself out of the server (is ssh access is all you have). You can simply repeat the installation process, but this time with a 'sudo git' first.

Comment: Well, the other option is Telnet, but I have no idea what that is.  So yeah, I think I've locked myself out.  Is there a way to undo that?

Comment: @Jay no way that I know of, but explorer that telnet option (it is a service like ssh except without encryption). Try a `telnet @ip_of_your_server` and see if you can connect that way.

Comment: Ok, I'm able to login via Telnet it looks like.  Do you know how I might use Telnet to redo the gitolite installation process? Thank you very much for all your help!!

Comment: @Jay: answer edited

Answer (score 0):

I agree that Gitolite probably should not be running as root. I made this mistake as well. Just adding some additional info in case it helps.

I was still able to SSH as root to the target machine by adding the following flags to my SSH command:

```
PreferredAuthentications=keyboard-interactive,password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no
```

Of course, this is assuming that your root account has a password associated with it. You will not be able to authenticate with a private key because of the way Gitosis edits the SSH known_hosts file, however that file is not consulted in any way if you specify you preferred authentication with the flags listed above.